# inserting node at the nth place in linked list(not able to understand my code)

Tags: c++

not able to understand the steps in [else statement] block .
please someone help me with it.I am trying to insert a node at the nth place keeping in mind the node at the nth position cannot be created unless node at (n-1)th has been created.

EDIT:-Now I have posted the complete code(working),

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



struct Node{
    int data;
    Node*next ;
};

void insertlinkedlist(Node**head,int data,int position)
{
    int k = 1;

Node *p,*q,*newNode;

    newNode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!newNode)
    {
        cout<<"Memory leak";
        return;
    }

    newNode->data = data;
    p=*head;

    if(position ==1)
    {
        newNode ->next = p;
        *head = newNode;
    }

    else {
        while(p!=NULL&k<position){
            k++;
            q=p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        q->next = newNode;
        newNode ->next = p;
    }
}

void display(Node*head)
{
    Node*ptr =  head;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}


int main(){
    Node*head = NULL;
    insertlinkedlist(&head, 34, 1);
     insertlinkedlist(&head, 3, 2);
     insertlinkedlist(&head, 13, 3);

    display(head);

    cout<<endl;


}
```

**output**

> 34 3 13

Comment: Please correct the code you have posted. At present it does not compile.

Comment: You realise that the else block is never entered because in your example position is always equal to 1?

Comment: for me, everything works fine

Comment: So... you wrote the code and it works but you don't understand *how* it works? Did you guess your way to a working program?

Comment: @RoQuTriX because this is a working code but I need help in understanding the statements in else block.

Comment: @NajmusSaqibMakhdoomi but your sample output would be wrong

Comment: in the else block it iterates throw the list until its end or until the required position. then, it links the current node to the new node and the new node to the next of the current node.

Comment: @molbdnilo .To be honest I copied the insertlinkedlist (function) from somewhere .

Comment: Yes, from a C program. If you are planning to use it, you should include the necessary headers, like `<cstdio>` and `<cstdlib>`, but I strongly suggest to rewrite it in a more idiomatic C++ way.

Comment: The best way to understand pointer-manipulating code is to draw the structure on paper with a pen or pencil, and update the drawing as you trace through the code in your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else statement is executed, when an element is not inserted at the first position. In your code referred with 1. I think it would be a better approach to declare the first position with a 0.
The while statement `p!=null` returns true (=0), when the pointer is valid. This value gets bitwise-anded with the return value of `k<position`. The while statement breaks therefore, when you are at your last element of the linked list or at your specified position.
After the while statement is executed you insert your new Node at the end or at the actual specified position at q, which gets calculated in the while-statement. After that you insert the next element after your `newNode`. Imagine a new element at position 3. Then this element is at position 3 and everyhting what comes after 3, starts at position 4.